# How to model data in dynamodb if your access pattern includes many WHERE conditions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am a bit confused if this is possible in DynamoDB.

I will give an example of SQL and explain how the query could be optimized and then I will try to explain why I am confused on how to model this and how to access the same data in DynamoDB.

This is not company code. Just an example I made up based on pcpartpicker filter.

```
SELECT * FROM BUILDS
WHERE CPU='Intel' AND 'OVERCLOCKED'='true'
AND Price < 3000
AND GPU='GeForce RTX 3060'
AND ...
```

From my understanding, SQL will first do a scan on the BUILDS table and then filter out all the builds where CPU is using intel. From this subset, it then does another WHERE clause to filter 'OVERCLOCEKD' = true so on and so forth. Basically, all of the additional WHERE clauses have a smaller number of rows to filter.

One thing we can do to speed up this query is to create an index on these columns. The main increase in performance is reducing the initial scan on the whole table for the first clause that the database looks at. So in the example above instead of scanning the whole db to find builds that are using intel it can quickly retrieve them since it is indexed.

How would you model this data in DynamoDB? I know you can create a bunch of secondary Indexes but instead of letting the engine do the WHERE clause and passing along the result to do the next set of filtering. It seems like you would have to do all of this yourself. For example, we would need to use our secondary index to find all the builds that use intel, overclocked, less than 3000, and using a specific GPU and then we would need to find the intersection ourselves. Is there a better way to map out this access pattern? I am having a hard time figuring out if this is even possible.

EDIT:
I know I could also just use a normal filter but it seems like this would be pretty expensive since it basically brute force search through the table similar to the SQL solution without indexing.

To see what I mean from pcpartpicker here is the link to the site with this page: https://pcpartpicker.com/builds/

People basically select multiple filters so it makes designing for access patterns even harder.

Comment: You're asking "how can I taste an apple while eating an orange" - just use RDS

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that may be the case. I am just trying to understand the limitations of DynamoDB. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Your use case isn't for DynamoDB, DynamoDB is for quick access to data not searching, sorting, filtering etc. Also possibly take a look at OpenSearch (ElasticSearch) or maybe even Redis but the answer is - you can't model this in DDB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd highly recommend going through the various AWS presentations on YouTube...

In particular here's a link to [The Iron Triangle of Purpose - PIE Theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwnNbLXN4vA&t=2530s)  chapter of the ***AWS re:Invent 2018: Building with AWS Databases: Match Your Workload to the Right Database (DAT301)*** presentation.
[image]

DynamoDB provides IE - Infinite Scale and Efficiency.

But you need P - Pattern Flexibility.

You'll need to decide if you need PI or PE.