# DynamoDB Modelling: Find all entities that match search term against various entity attributes

Tags: sql, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, data-modeling

I am new to DynamoDB and the world of NoSQL in general, and although I have purchased and read Alex DeBrie's DynamoDB book, I still couldn't figure this out.

**Scenario:**

I want to build an app with one of those "cool" searches where you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and get a search modal and within the search modal, you can type anything, and it will bring up your matches. See [TailwindCSS's doc page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) for an example.

My entities are `Organisation` and `Customer`. There is a one-to-many relationship between them. One organisation has many customers.

Had this been SQL, I imagine myself something something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM customers c
WHERE c.id LIKE '%search-term%'
OR c.first_name LIKE '%search-term%'
OR c.last_name LIKE '%search-term%'
OR c.date_of_birth LIKE '%search-term%'
OR c.phone_number LIKE '%search-term%'
OR c.post_code LIKE '%search-term%'
```

But in DynamoDB, I'm not sure how I can get the same functionality.

**Current Model:**

So far I have the following:

[image: data model]

This only allows me to search by *customer Id*.

**Useful Info:**

An organisation can have thousands of customers, but let's say on average, an organisation will have 50K customers, 15K of which will be active (i.e. should come up in the search), inactive customers should not come up in the search unless requested.

I hear you ask, how will the user request this? I'll have a bit of info text that says:

> Place an `*` in front of the search term to also search through inactive customers.

The most common look up for a customer would be by name, for example `A Watson`, but of course they can just as well search by post code, e.g. `ls11 3fd` (can be lowercase or uppercase).

The attributes that I do want to search against are:

- Customer Id
- Customer First Name
- Customer Last Name
- Customer Date of Birth
- Customer Phone Number
- Customer Post Code

The customer entity will have between 20 to 30 attributes but for the purposes of the search modal, the results coming back will only have first name, last name, date of birth, assigned customer rep, and the 1st line of address and post code (so 6 attributes).

**Thoughts so far:**

1. Create a GSI for each attribute I want to search by (so 5 GSIs in my case).
2. Create own index. When a customer is added to the application, I insert `pk` as `search#org#1` and the `sk` as `byfirstname#Ray`, then the other attributes that I want, then another item with the same `pk` but this time with the `sk` as `bylastname#Charles` and so on.

With option 2, I have to remember to update the items when the entity is updated, I can do so via DynamoDB stream and a lambda invocation.

If I go with option, I'm not really sure why my DynamoDB query will look like!

How can I model the table given the above information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to model data in dynamodb if your access pattern includes many WHERE conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901071/how-to-model-data-in-dynamodb-if-your-access-pattern-includes-many-where-conditi)

Comment: This is a very poor use of DDB.

Comment: How so @Charles? I have other access patterns that don't have this requirement, but it wouldn't make sense to use DDD for those, and only move this bit out to a Relational database?

Comment: Do you read the linked to answer and watch the AWS presentations?  DDB is a poor choice when you need robust searches.   Opensearch or RDS would be a much better choice.

Comment: I would suggest using service like ElasticSearch for search engine purpose. Dynamodb is not a great tool for search. The idea is you have to index your data and using any service/tool/library to perform full-text search/ fuzzy or whatever text based search.